# How to embed velocity "vm" file inside eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt, velocity

I have to use velocity for development of eclipse plugins.. I am using Velocity 1.5. I have created some vm files which i need to packaged with eclipse swt plugins..

If i run the application through eclipse, the plugins showing error "xxx.vm" is not located.

Please help!!!

Comment: How do you locate your Velocity files - are you using classpath or FileLocator?

Answer (score 2):

Please check plugin build.properties. Make sure .vm files are included in the build.

Comment: How to include vm file. I am not able to find a single example for the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following items:

- check that you are having files inside the plugin part of the classpath, I think this is always the case with Eclipse plugins, just check that "." is part of the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF
  Bundle-ClassPath: lib/local-lib.jar,
   .,
- as stated, ensure that the files are actually bundled with the plugin, e.g. check the resulting jar-file and see if the files are in there. If not, adjust your build to include them.
- Use a ClasspathResourceLoader in the Velocity configuration, e.g.

  ```
  ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class");
  ve.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
  ```

Then you should be able to get velocity templates by simply stating the full name relative to the base directory of the plugin.

See http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Resource_Loaders for details.